# "Syncretic" vs "Syncretistic" with negative connotation

Tags: etymology, connotation

I need to translate a sentence from Greek which literally sounds something like this:

> At that time a ***syncretic/syncretistic spirit*** prevailed and the X (name of nation) were influenced by the beliefs of the peoples around them.

My concern is the bold part. The context of the sentence definitely requires a negative connotation and I wonder which between ***syncretic*** and ***syncretistic*** carry a more negative connotation, meaning *too inclusive, and therefore diluting certain beliefs*.

*Syncretic* is easy to find in dictionaries, but the definitions I get seem pretty neutral. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/syncretic) describes this term as *specialized*. When defining *syncretistic* the [FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/syncretistic) speaks about *reconciliation or fusion* which have nothing negative about them. Other dictionaries simply say ***see syncretism***.

My intuition says that *syncretistic* must be the more pejorative one, maybe influenced by the feel I have of the [***suffix -istic***](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=-istic) in comparison with what seems to me the more neutral [***-ic***](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ic?ref=etymonline_crossreference). It is only an intuition though, and it might be completely wrong since words like *stylistic* or *patristic* carry no negative connotations. I would be thrilled to find proof for my intuition being right or wrong.

Comment: Did you read this? *Is There A Difference Between “Syncretic” and “Syncretistic”?: A Suggestion:* http://polytheist.com/speaking-of-syncretism/2015/03/17/is-there-a-difference-between-syncretic-and-syncretistic/

Comment: @user66974 No, I actually hadn't read that. But it does seem to me rather subjective... Also I am more interested in a word that would characterise a _tendency_ or _spirit_ rather than _religions_ as in the well-known set phrase.

Comment: in English, fascistic is fascist-like. syncretistic like syncretic-like. Of course, tic or ic is not always like. By the way, the only knowledge I have of this is the fusion of Afro-religious beliefs (like Candomblé) and Catholicism in Brazil. I don't see why  you can't state the name of the nation in the question.

Comment: ... 'My suggestion of 'syncretism' by the above author, one who has used and researched these words, shows that there cannot be a consensus even in the areas where they _are_ used. Such stipulative definitions would be off-topic on a general English usage site in any case. // I know how I've always regarded 'syncretism' and thus 'syncretic'; 'syncretistic' I've never heard.

Comment: @Lambie It's from a book to be published. Just thought I should be vague :)

Answer (score 1):

> My concern is the bold part. The context of the sentence definitely requires a negative connotation

The OED should dispel your concern - it is negative:

> **syncretic,** adj. and n.
>
> **Etymology**: < **syncretism<sup>1</sup>** n., probably after docetic, docetism.
>
> A. adj.
>
> **1. Characterized by syncretism; aiming at a union or reconciliation of diverse beliefs, practices, or systems.**
>
> 1853   Fraser's Mag. 47 293   *The philosophy which at the time Minucius was writing arrayed itself against Christianity, was..syncretic.*
>
> 1884   A. H. Sayce Anc. Empires East 204   *The syncretic spirit of Phœnician art.*

> **<sup>1</sup>syncretism**, n.
>
> **Etymology**: < modern Latin syncrētismus (D. Pareus, 1615), < Greek συγκρητισμός , < συγκρητίζειν to syncretize v. Compare French syncrétisme, *‘the ioyning, or agreement, of two enemies against a third person’* (Cotgrave).
>
> **1. Attempted union or reconciliation of diverse or opposite tenets or practices, esp. in philosophy or religion;** spec. the system or principles of a school founded in the 17th century by George Calixtus, who aimed at harmonizing the sects of Protestants and ultimately all Christian bodies: see Calixtin n. 2   **(Almost always in derogatory sense.)**
>
> 1778   E. Apthorp Lett. Prevalence Christianity 162   This divine light..was..obscured by the prevailing syncretism of true and false religion.
>
> 1852   W. Hamilton Discuss. Philos. & Lit. 409   Their particular dissensions were merged in a general syncretism to resist the novelty equally obnoxious to all.
>
> 1853   Fraser's Mag. 47 294   Syncretism, under every possible form—ethical, political, social, and theological, was the favourite policy of the Roman emperors. They would have all the varieties of mankind called in and restamped at the Cæsarean mint.

That said, the OED entry is noted:

> This entry has not yet been fully updated (first published 1919; most recently modified version published online June 2018).

And there have been since the mid-20th century, ecumenical movements towards closer understanding (albeit short of fusion - syncretism.)

However, the basic meaning and use is still with some deprecatory effect.

**Edit to add:**

> **syncretistic**, adj.
>
> **Belonging to, or having the character of, a syncretist or syncretists; relating to, or characterized by, syncretism. *Also = syncretic adj.***
>
> 1828   E. B. Pusey Hist. Enq. Rationalist Char. I. i. 57   *The signal for the Syncretistic controversy given by Buscher in his work against Calixtus.*
>
> 1926   M. Warden tr. J. Piaget Lang. & Thought of Child iv. 132   *To this childish form of perception M. Claparède has given the name of syncretistic perceptions, using the name chosen by Renan to denote that first ‘wide and comprehensive but obscure and inaccurate’ activity of the spirit where ‘no distinction is made and things are heaped one upon the other’.*
>
> 1976   S. Arieti Creativity ix. 195   *The artist or viewer has a syncretistic grasp of the total object. He abandons precise visualization and experiences an unclear vision of the whole.*

Also

> **syncreˈtistical** adj.
>
> 1764   A. Maclaine tr. J. L. von Mosheim Eccl. Hist. Cent. xvii. ii. i. §21 (margin)    *The rise of the Syncretistical or Calixtine controversies.*

Comment: Good, that helps, I don't have access to the OED. Does the OED mention syncretistic at all?

Comment: @fev It does. The issue is that *syncretistic* is also negative, certainly in examples like this:  1976   S. Arieti Creativity ix. 195   The artist or viewer has a syncretistic grasp of the total object. He abandons precise visualization and experiences an unclear vision of the whole.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Your quoted example helps me see how the term is used in a non-religious context. Appreciate your contribution.

Comment: @fev Yes, I should have included it - I have done now + syncretical.

Comment: If the 'also' isn't part of the quote, there needs to be a definition of 'syncretistical' to compare. // The words seem largely synonymous; OED doesn't examine the shades of meaning in the article 'Is There A Difference Between “Syncretic” and “Syncretistic”?: A Suggestion' mentioned above. I'm glad to see.

Comment: "Syncretic" would be insulting to a traditional Christian who would see it as corrupt or blasphemous. Today when there  is more respect for the culture of others, and particularly the faiths of marginalised groups who have traditionally embraced syncretic belief systems, it is less negative, as the current dictionary definitions show. So whether it's bad or not depends on your point of view (just as a word like "atheist" might).